# Cannot find file path (invalid url)

Tags: php, html, href

I have problem to find file path. I have a form that can insert file or image.

Below code shows how the file or images save

```php
    if($_FILES["lampiran"]["name"][$i] != "")
    {
        $my_folder = "./files";
        $location = $my_folder.'/'.$pname;

        $imageFileType = pathinfo($tname,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        move_uploaded_file($tname,$location);

        $query2 = "INSERT into list_lampiran (id_aduan, folder, lampiran, nama_asal, type, size, time_create) VALUES ('$id_aduan', '$my_folder', '$location', '$pname', '$file_type', '$file_size', '$time_create')";

    mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    $id_lampiran=mysqli_insert_id($con);

        if($query2){

            $myfile_rename = $id_lampiran.'_'.$pname;  

            rename($location, './files/'.$myfile_rename); 

            $query3 ="UPDATE list_lampiran SET lampiran = '$myfile_rename' WHERE id = '$id_lampiran'";      

            mysqli_query($con,$query3);

        }

    }
```

Then the file or image will sent through an email and appear as a link. But the link have invalid URL

Code to display the file or image in email

```php
     if(mysqli_num_rows($resultlampiran) > 0){

      $rowlampiran = mysqli_fetch_array($resultlampiran, 
                     MYSQLI_ASSOC);
       $folder_name = $rowlampiran['folder'];
       $lampiran = $rowlampiran['lampiran'];
       $lampiran1 = $folder_name.'/'.$lampiran;
       $nama_asal = $rowlampiran['nama_asal'];
       $file = "<ul><li><a href='".$lampiran1."'>".$nama_asal."</a></li></ul>"; }
```

[Redirect notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJKRl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to include the URL of your website in the file link. You need to update the file path in your email template or so as:

```
$website = "https://example.com/";
$file = "<ul><li><a href='".$website.$lampiran1."'>".$nama_asal."</a></li</ul>";
```

and you're good to go :)

> *Also, you have coded without caring about the security of your application. Anyone could easy upload backdoor or any other PHP
>   scripts and destroy all the data and files on your server. You must
>   validate file extension and then save to your database*

Example:

```
$validExt = array("jpg", "png", "pdf", "txt"); // valid extensions that should only be allowed.

// and then check if upload file's extension matches in our valid list
if(in_array(strtolower($imageFileType), $validExt) === false) {
// some other file extension found, show error message
} else {
// upload your file here and save to database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your file url

```
$location = "www.sitename.com/". $my_folder.'/'.$pname;
echo $location;
```

Comment: this will lead to file uploading error. Since move_uploaded_file() function will be expecting a relative or absolute path not a path with domain name :(

Comment: No, there is no issue in his code. he wants to know where exactly his file is stored after upload so I have shared the location of the uploaded files. He can access his files by providing domain name, folder name and name of the file.

Comment: hmm that's okay. This misunderstanding was due to the lack of explanation for your reply . :)